# Prerequisites for E. Frenkel's "Langlands correspondance for loop groups"

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, langlands-program

What would be the prerequisites to understand the material in this book ? It is advertised as an undergraduate course, but it seems this would apply to either very dedicated or quite advanced students after reading the first pages.

https://math.berkeley.edu/~frenkel/loop.pdf

Would one need representation theory, elements of algebraic number theory ,modular forms and some Lie group theory, as explained in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49179 or is Frenkel's book truly a more accessible introduction ?

Comment: It looks relatively self-contained. I would say the prerequisites are some basic lie theory and mathematical maturity ( if you skip the first chapter) and the first chapter is not relevant to the rest of the book.